# call a c# .net aspx script from regular html

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

how can i do a form POST from a regular html file. and call a .net file that ends with .aspx
what would my html file require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form method="Post" action="YourNETFile.aspx">
   ... other form elements
</form>
```

Then on your aspx code behind, you can get to the form elements with:
    Request.Params["FormElementName"]

Comment: The only thing I would add is that your aspx file might need to have viewstate validation turned off.

Answer (score 0):

something of the form

```
<form action="location of aspx" method="Get|post">
   <input name="variable name" value="variable value" type="text|hidden|etc" />
</form>
```

such as:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Just put it as the `action` of the form.  All you need to remember is to make sure your fields are named what the CodeBehind expects.

Cheers!

p.s.  It seems that posting answers is now a game of "beat the clock"

Comment: Heh, posting answers has been a game of "beat the clock" for some time ;)